# import characters in python from .csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding

I have a simple question regarding importing .csv data.
I have large .csv files containing information. I import each row and transform that in a list, then I create a list of lists. Some columns contain integers some contain strings. As the data gets written into .csv files, there are columns that contain Imperial feet and fractional inches.
So the original data is  4' - 8 1/2" (four feet and eight and a half inches). When I import the .csv in Python in order to compare data, these cells get as '4\' - 8 1/2"'.

if I try to use codecs and decode to utf-8 or ascii I do not get any results
import codecs

```
s = '4\' - 8 1/2"'
>>> ss = s.decode("utf-8")
>>> ss
'4\' - 8 1/2"'
>>> ss = s.decode("ascii")
>>> ss
'4\' - 8 1/2"'
```

Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct `string` type it has to be written like this another wise you will get wrong result.
If you check by `type(ss)`, you see it's a string.

If you print it out `print(ss)`, you get `4' - 8 1/2"`.
So if you compare it with a string look exactly same. It will return `True`